# Registering extension for NHibernate

Tags: .net, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, extension-methods

I would like to use "Equals" to check wether a value in my DB and another given value are the same.
Unfortunatly, NHbernate does not seam to support "Equals", so I searched in the internet and found this tutorial: http://www.primordialcode.com/blog/post/nhibernate-3-extending-linq-provider-fix-notsupportedexception
At the end, I have to register the extension - but in which file should I do that?

**Edit**
Maybe I should describe my problem a bit better...
*The situation:* I have a enumeration called "GoodsType". Possible values are for example "Iron", "Wood", "Stone", etc.  This enum is used in the class "InventoryGoods":

```
public class InventoryGoods: Goods
{
    public virtual User Owner { get; set; }
    public virtual Guid Id { get; set; }
    public virtual long Amount { get; set; }
    public virtual GoodsType GoodsType { get; set; }
    public virtual float Price { get; set; }
}
```

If a user want to sell something, I have to check wether he has enough of this specific good. I created a function for this check. This function is able to find the actual Owner by itself (the user which is logged in), so I only have to send the GoodsType and the Amount.
But if I use this request: `InventoryGoods good = _repository.First(x => (Equals(x.GoodsType, GivenGoodsType)) && (x.Amount >= GivenAmount));`, the script stops with the error *System.NotSupportedException: Boolean Equals(System.Object, System.Object)*

I searched a lot, and somewhere on SO (unfortunatly I don't remember the link) I found the statement that "Equals" is not supported by NHibernate (because it is not translateable to SQL). So I searched for a solution and found the tutorial named above. But I'm unable to find the file where I have to register the extension.

I already found this solution: `InventoryGoods good = _repository.First(x => x.Amount >= GivenAmount).Where(x => (Equals(x.GoodsType, GivenGoodsType)));`, but I would prefer a way without double-checking via "Where", only with "First".

**Edit 2**
I'm using Fluent NHibernate for my mapping.

Answer (score 0):

As long as I know, NHibernate supports Equals for object comparison. In fact, you should override it, as long as default equals implementation relays on memory address, not object values.

See this similar questions:
[Why is it important to override GetHashCode when Equals method is overridden?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/371328/why-is-it-important-to-override-gethashcode-when-equals-method-is-overriden-in-c)

[NHibernate: Reasons for overriding Equals and GetHashCode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5851398/nhibernate-reasons-for-overriding-equals-and-gethashcode)

Comment: It does not seam to supports "equals" - or I'm doing something wrong. If I try to use it like `return _repository.First(x => x.GoodsType.Equals(GoodsTypeToCheck));` it throws the error `System.NotSupportedException: Boolean Equals(System.Object)`

Comment: What are you trying to do? Get assemblies of certain type?

Comment: Also, notice that the article you reference says that he was used an alpha release of version 3, current GA version is 3.3.0 stable. Are you using latest version?

Comment: I updated my question, I hope, it is clearer now. I think I'm using a new version of NHibernate, but where can I check that?

Comment: In NHibernate's sourceforge page, of course! Check if your NHibernate.dll version is the same as the latest release at:
http://sourceforge.net/projects/nhibernate/

Comment: I updated my version - but the error still occurs :-( I'm sorry, but I just saw that I seem to have forgotten to write that I'm using Fluent NHibernate - does this make any difference?